# Error [System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'gdi32.dll' or one of its dependencies]?

Tags: system.drawing.common

I build a Application NetCore 3.1 ,it using System.Drawing.Common.dll and run on ubuntu

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'gdi32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libgdi32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried the below in docker file, but no luck. still getting the same error.

#install libgdiplus for System.Drawing
RUN apt-get update 
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libgdiplus libc6-dev libx11-dev libc6
RUN apt-get update 
&& apt-get install -y apt-utils libgdiplus libc6-de

Answer (score 0):

GDI is a Windows-native library.  Supposedly there's a [Linux version](https://en.code-bude.net/2017/05/08/net-core-gdiplus-dll-not-found-in-linux/).  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: we are using the DLLImport in our code, should we change the DLLimport code to System.Drawing.Graphics ?. example of DLLImport are -> [DllImport("usp10.dll")] and [DllImport("gdi32.dll")